# hyper-card interface builder in javascript?

Tags: javascript, interface-builder, wysiwyg

I've been playing with approaches to "editable mashups" - somewhat inspired by HyperCard on the front-end, Yahoo Pipes on the backend.

There are some nice tools for "plumbing" dataflows - deri pipes being the most complete.

What I'm wondering is if there are any interface builders, or js libraries, that run completely in a browser window - the way that HyperCard let one simply go into "edit mode," then drag and drop interface elements (buttons, fields, widgets) on the page; link those elements to code; and end up with a fully functional web page?

Answer (score 0):

I do want to see (or build) a project like this. But I believe it should be done the right way, with a focus on user experience. I think the benefits of writing a custom editor, in terms of having control over the ui, outweigh the cost of the effort involved. With modern JS libraries DHTML has become easier.

The Internet needs HyperCard - to inspire people to make things. (Just like client-side js, anyone could open a HyperCard stack and view the source). I've made good progress on a rough clone. What I don't know yet, though, is how to design this for mobile, or ipads, where the need may be even greater.